# why my discord bots create script is not working?

Tags: python

I am a beginner python coder and i have been learning about how to create `discord bots` and i ran into an error but I don't know how to fix it.
Can anyone tell me why this code below is not working?
I have already tried many things including editing my code in `notepad++`.

```py
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time


Client = discord.Client()

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "@")


@client.event

async def on_ready():
    
    
        print("Yo im here cuz DaNewNotch created me like a wizard")

        
@client.event

async def on_message(message):
    
    if message.content.upper().startswith("@PING"):
        
        userID = message.author.id
        
await client.send_message(message.channel, "<@%s> Pong!" % (userID))
    
    if message.content.upper(),startswith("@AIAA")

    if "&537760658079350789" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
        
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Yes <%s> you are")

    else:
```

Comment: might want to include the code and the problem

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: i get unindent does not match any outer indent level

Comment: i fixed the previous promblem but have discovered that python is saying else: is an invalid snytax at the bottom

Comment: I would recommend reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and following [mcve]. It would help us to be better understand and answer your question, and you might even find the answer to the question yourself before asking it.

Comment: pls dont use `on_message` this is very ugly and if you want your bot to have a lot of command that will be unreadable as well use this instead https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html

Answer (score 0):

I think the lines `await client.send_message(message.channel, "<@%s> Pong!" % (userID))` and `await client.send_message(message.channel, "Yes <%s> you are")` are underindented and therefore not executing. You could try properly indenting them. Also one if statement is missing the `:` at the end. It would also be very helpful for us to answer your question if you provided a stack trace. I think what you were going for was:

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time

Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "@")

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Yo im here cuz DaNewNotch created me like a wizard")

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.upper().startswith("@PING"):
        userID = message.author.id
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "<@%s> Pong!" % (userID))
    if message.content.upper().startswith("@AIAA"):
        if "&537760658079350789" in [role.id for role in message.author.roles]:
            await client.send_message(message.channel, "Yes <%s> you are")
```

Also, you were calling `,startswith` instead of `.startswith` I recommend you get an actual Python IDE so your code will be less garbage and filled with errors

Comment: you could try the PyCharm IDE I think its pretty decent. You can download it at https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/download/